# D3 Dynamic Bar Chart Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, visualization

I have a bar chart that updates at regular intervals, but the issue is that there's a new bar chart created every time the update function is called and it just stacks on top of one another, if you zoom in and out you'll notice the issue. I initially moved some elements of the code outside of the update function to resolve it, but as I changed some numbers in the data, to see if the bar chart was updating, it wasn't doing it. So I brought it back in and now I'm stuck with the issue.

Here is my code and I have the update interval set to 3 seconds, so you can notice what's happening.

https://plnkr.co/edit/5ivBgVsMK9RTWQRw?preview

csv data:

```
month,revenue,profit
January,123432,180034
February,19342,10342
March,17443,15423
April,26342,18432
May,34213,29434
June,50321,45343
July,54273,80002
August,60000,30344
September,44432,32444
October,21332,9974
November,79105,48711
December,45246,21785
```

Comment: If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you still appending on every update, try to open inspector (right click in browser page and select Inspect) and look to HTML code.
Make `append` only first time and on update only modify or recreate whole structure on update

EDIT
here is example with random data on every update:

```
// Add your code here
const MARGIN = {
  LEFT: 100,
  RIGHT: 40,
  TOP: 10,
  BOTTOM: 130
}
// total width incl margin
const VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 1140;
// total height incl margin
const VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 400;

const WIDTH = VIEWPORT_WIDTH - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT
const HEIGHT = VIEWPORT_HEIGHT - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM

flag = true

const svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", WIDTH + MARGIN.LEFT + MARGIN.RIGHT)
  .attr("height", HEIGHT + MARGIN.TOP + MARGIN.BOTTOM)

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP})`);

d3.csv("data.csv").then(data => {
  data.forEach(d => {
      d.profit = Number(d.profit)
      d.revenue = Number(d.revenue)
      d.month = d.month
  })


  d3.interval(() => {
      update(data)
  }, 300)

  update(data)
})


function update(data) {

  d3.csv("data.csv").then(data => {
      data.forEach((d, i) => {
          d.profit = ((Math.random() * 100000) + 100)
          d.revenue = ((Math.random() * 10000) + 100)
          d.month = d.month
      })

      const x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, WIDTH])
          .paddingInner(0.3)
          .paddingOuter(0.2)
          .domain(data.map(d => d.month))

      var y0 = d3.max(data, d => d.profit)
      var y1 = d3.max(data, d => d.revenue)

      var maxdomain = y1

      if (y0 > y1) var maxdomain = y0;

      const xAxisGroup = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`)

      const yAxisGroup = g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")


      const barsGroup = g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'bars');

      const zoomGroup = barsGroup.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'zoom');

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([HEIGHT, 0])
          .domain([0, maxdomain])

      const xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x)
      xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall)
          .selectAll("text")
          .attr("y", "10")
          .attr("x", "-5")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-40)")

      const yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y)
          .ticks(4)
          .tickFormat(d => "$" + d)

      yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);

      const monthGroups = zoomGroup.selectAll('g.month')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'month');

      const rectsProfit = monthGroups
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "profit")
          .attr("y", d => y(d.profit))
          .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month))
          .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", d => HEIGHT - y(d.profit))
          .attr("fill", "grey");

      const rectsRevenue = monthGroups
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "revenue")
          .attr("y", d => y(d.revenue))
          .attr("x", (d) => x(d.month) + 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
          .attr("width", 0.5 * x.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", d => HEIGHT - y(d.revenue))
          .attr("fill", "red")

      const defs = svg.append('defs');
      const barsClipPath = defs.append('clipPath')
          .attr('id', 'bars-clip-path')
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', 0)
          .attr('width', WIDTH)
          .attr('height', 400);

      barsGroup.attr('clip-path', 'url(#bars-clip-path)');
      
      xAxisGroup.attr('clip-path', 'url(#bars-clip-path)');

      
      const zoom = d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([0.5, Infinity])
          .on("zoom", ({ transform }) => {
              const scaleFactor = transform.k;
              
              const xOffset = transform.x;
              
              zoomGroup.attr('transform', `translate(${xOffset} 0) scale(${scaleFactor} 1)`);

              
              x.range([xOffset, WIDTH * scaleFactor + xOffset]);
              xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall)
          });

      
      svg.call(zoom);
  })
}
```

you see how update bars, and overlaying every time

Comment: I tried, what you said, but I am unable to get only the bars to update, what happens is, the y-axis scale updates, but the bars don't. In the code, I attached, everything updates as it should, but the bars and x-axis keep getting overlapped.

Comment: but what you mean about using `ReCharts` except `D3` directly?
https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleBarChart
Solution with `D3` it's more flexible, but in usual cases it's enough

Comment: I'm trying to learn D3 currently. I'll look into your suggestion later.